# Vulgarities in the vim Default Dictionary

Tags: spell-checking

I use Vim to write LaTeX, in particular professional, academic papers.  I rely on the default vim dictionary (in `/usr/local/share/vim/vim81/spell/en.utf-8.spl`).  I recently noticed a vulgarity (variant of "shift") was not marked as spelled incorrect.

I checked the vim dictionary via `:spelldump` and noticed a slew of vulgarities.  Is there a way for all such words to not appear in the dictionary by default?  The "shift" error is one example where an unintentionally misspelled vulgarity would be marked as spelled correctly.

Comment: You could remove them--is that not the solution you're looking for?

Comment: @D.BenKnoble But can you remove them using a small override dictionary file in your home directory? Or should you copy the system file to your home directory, to fork it, then modify it? Modifying the system one is not always possible (owned by root) and modifications are likely to be erased on an upgrade of the system Vim packages...

Comment: Well @filbranden you can set `spellfile`

Comment: @D.BenKnoble I was hoping to avoid manually changing the default dict for a few reasons.  For example, there may be also words I may not think of.  filbranden raises other good points. When I posted the question, I assumed it was a problem other folks had run into as well, and there was an "off the shelf" solution.